# Common database name Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio, entity-framework

I use Entity Framework 6 code-first in a Windows application to connect to a SQL Server database. How could I edit my code to enable me or any app user to change the database name without getting any errors?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the connection string separately in the configuration file and then use [ConfigurationManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) class to read strings.

But to change only the database name without other errors, you must ensure that other settings are the same. Otherwise, you must modify the corresponding code or settings according to the actual situation.

For example: add in the configuration file (config)

```
<connectionStrings>
     <add name="MyDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=myServer;Initial Catalog=myDatabase;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Then call it like this:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDbContext"].ConnectionString;
```

For detailed examples, please refer to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#examples).